# download no machine v 3.5

Tags: 12.04, vps

I am looking for `no machine` version 3.5 for Ubuntu 14.10 64 bit.

I did install v4 before and it's not stable and watching videos is a little bit slow. I read that 3.5 is better and is there a solution to play sound in the vpsremote desktop because it doesn't play sounds.

I found this code but don't understand how it works:

```
MAJOR_PV="$(get_version_component_range 1-3)"
FULL_PV="${MAJOR_PV}-$(get_version_component_range 4)"
DESCRIPTION="Free edition NX server from NoMachine"
HOMEPAGE="http://www.nomachine.com/"
SRC_URI="amd64? ( http://64.34.161.181/download/${MAJOR_PV}/Linux/FE/nxserver-${FULL_PV}.x86_64.tar.gz )
    x86? ( http://64.34.161.181/download/${MAJOR_PV}/Linux/FE/nxserver-${FULL_PV}.i386.tar.gz )"
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated on [NoMachine website](https://www.nomachine.com/version-3) version 3 it is no longer officialy provided and they link to some open source alternatives (FreeNX, NeatX, X2Go, 2X and Xpra).

If you really want 3.5, you can download it from [Web Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20130503082042/http://www.nomachine.com/download.php) - choose DEB packages for Ubuntu. There are installation instructions under links, and here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NomachineNX

Keep in mind that 3.5 version is no longer supported and can contain security vulnerabilities.

Comment: the nxnode_3.5.0 did't succeded to download it 404 not found :(

Comment: what is it's utility is it important so that i can connect from my windows 7 to my ubuntu computer

Comment: There seem to be missing nxnode and nxserver for 64bit systems. You could try downloading 32bit and running with ia32-libs. But keep in mind that 3.5 version is no longer supported and can contain security vulnerabilities - but there are some open source alternatives like: FreeNX, NeatX, X2Go, 2X and Xpra.

Comment: thanks it installed but now iget this error when i try to connect from windows to my ubuntu "no subscription information found on the server" i found this tutorial https://www.nomachine.com/AR01G00522 but i don't have  key.tar.gz

Comment: You have installed "NX Free Edition for Linux"?
here are some installation instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NomachineNX

Comment: Here is the direct download link: http://web.archive.org/web/20130511020252/http://www.nomachine.com/download-package.php?Prod_Id=3829